# Google Calendar API 403 errors for 2022 dates

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a script that creates Google Calendar events (via the Google Calendar API), inviting/auto-accepting the classroom, teacher and students (all users within our G Suite for Education account). (Yes, it is [written in Perl](https://github.com/JustApu/vcClassCalSync) but I don't think that is the problem.)  Using this script, I manage 500-600 calendar events per school day.

There is enough rate limiting in the code and quota available in Google API Console that I can create a couple months worth of events in a nightly run.  So I usually push one grading period into Google Calendar at a time.  (I have over 37,000 events for this 2021-22 school year already pushed to Google Calendar.)  This has worked since August 2018.

But, for the past month or so, if I try to create events after mid-January 2022, I get a "Forbidden (403)" after about 50 events are created.  However, if I need to change 2021 or early 2022 events (for example, there is an assembly scheduled at school and the class times change, or a class moves from one room to another), I can delete/update/create the usual thousands of events per run with no problem.

As an example, tonight's run deleted and re-created 517 events for January 5, 2022 (there was a schedule change for that day) and made a few other miscellaneous changes, but only created 50 events for January 13, 2022 before a "Forbidden (403)"  I'm not going to be able to create anything for a few hours. But, after that (or tomorrow), I'll be able to create 50 more events and then hit the same error again.

Did I miss a change to the API effective with events scheduled in the second week of 2022?

[image: API metrics]
[image: Today's request totals]
[image: Query counts]
[image: Quotas]

Comment: Usually Calendar API quotas are maximum 600 per minute per user. I am very surprised your limit is 600,000. Did you ask for a quota increase? If so, did you do it recently?

Comment: It's an old project (Aug. 2018) so our quota has been going up steadily. Last increase was before this school year started, probably even during the last school year. (And, my project is rate limited so we don't get anywhere near the 600,000. I try to keep it at near one per second.)

Answer (score 0):

### If you are confident that the quotas you use are way below the limits, you might be affected by a bug

There is a already an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/182497593) filed on Google's Issue Tracker where several users complain about `limit being reach while console shows only 2% of limit being used`  - so similar to your case.

I recomend you to "star" this issue to increase visibility.

However, beforehand it might worth contacting the [Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?visit_id=637753504926292070-3540759390&rd=1). They can look into your quota usage and see if you are using some "idden quota" you ar enot aware of.

Comment: Thanks. I did reach out to Google Workspace Support. Conveniently, they referred me to this Stack Overflow post in their attempts to help me - not realizing it was I that had posted it in the first place. They said they made some change in the backend and I should wait 24 hours. I did that and created exactly 60 events today before getting the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately here we cannot look into your internal quota information. If support team could not spot any quota usage above the limit - chances are you are affected by the bug linked above. I guess your bets bet would be to implement an [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#exponential-backoff) as suggested in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/guides/errors#403_user_rate_limit_exceeded) to make your requests even slower than one per second.